# Dimension Security in OLAP Cubes

Tags: security, olap, cubes, cube-dimension

I have defined dimension security in my OLAP cube by creating roles and assigning users to each roles. Each user in a role can only see the location they belong to.

When I browse the cube using a role , I see correct location for that role. But, when I browse the cube using "Other User" feature in "Change User" and test it for the same user which exist in the role, it fails and I see all the locations.

What could be the problem?

Thanks,
Kailash

Comment: Are you directly accessing cube or using PerformancePoint or Reporting Services as a front end?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is here:
[CurrentMember (MDX) Ignores Slicer Dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746757/currentmember-mdx-ignores-slicer-dimension)

If you continue to use roles, I advise you to carefully read about 'Visual Totals' if your OLAP provider supports them.
Sorry I can't be more helpful.